# Ubuntu 18 scale problem

Tags: screen, mate

Recently i have upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18. Usually i use Mate desktop and the upgrade was made in Mate session via command line. 
The problem is, that when i log into Ubuntu desktop it is as if scaled to 200% i can see only one quarter of the desktop and i can reach other corners with mouse.
I have checked the scale option in settings: it is 100%, so the problem is not here.
When i log back to Mate, it is all right.
I have rebooted several times and ran "sudo dpkg --configure -a" (if it matters).

Comment: That sounds like a resolution problem not a scale problem. Scale tends to be the size of text and icons whereas resolution will affect the size/shape of the desktop. Do you have another monitor/tv you could connect to to see if the issue persists?? I'd check your resolution settings in gnome and see if changing it to a lower resolution and back again will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was zoom (in Universal access) enabled.