# Ubuntu 18.04 - Resolution is stuck at 640x480, can't change it

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, monitor

So yesterday I booted up my Ubuntu and found that the screen is stuck at a resolution of 640x480. How it came to this I don't know, I haven't changed anything other than updating the system.

The settings come up empty; it doesn't show any resolution at all, just an empty box. I have tried to re-install the nvidia-390 driver (graphics card is Nvidia Geforce GTX 750 Ti) and to manually build it into the kernel, but to no avail. Nothing I do has worked. Please help, this is tiring quickly and I need my pc.

Extra info: it seems that monitor "1" is in use instead of monitor "0" (echo $DISPLAY results in :1).

Answer (score 1):

Solved, according to this thread: [Graphics and resolution problems (Nvidia) in Ubuntu 18.04 after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191638/graphics-and-resolution-problems-nvidia-in-ubuntu-18-04-after-update?rq=1)

Summary: purged nvidia-390 and installed nvidia-340.