# on ubuntu 20.04 it wont let me set native resolution

Tags: 20.04, screen, display-resolution, monitor

on ubuntu 20.04 it wont let me set native resolution
I try to set the screen resolution to `1920x1080 (16:9)` but the option doesn't show and the only option is `1024x768 (4:3)`

[image: Screenshot of display settings]

[image]

This is what I get from `xrandr`

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

This is what I get from `sudo lshw -C video`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

And I use an ASUS ROG with an RTX 2060 and my monitor is a DELL S2440Lb connected via HDMI

Comment: Please update your original question with some more information such as what is the make/model of your monitor? How is your monitor connected to the PC? Please post the full results of running `xrandr` in a terminal.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `lshw -C video`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graphics and resolution problems (Nvidia) in Ubuntu 18.04 after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191638/graphics-and-resolution-problems-nvidia-in-ubuntu-18-04-after-update)

Comment: Sometimes your monitor settings just aren't detected properly and you need to set a custom modeline. This might be of use https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/